# Link structure visible to user - PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a site built in PHP which shows the companies basic information:

so for example:

http://marketplace.com/company?id=5

Shows me information about company number 5 - name Blueberries

http://marketplace.com/company?id=6

Shows me information about company number 6 - name Potatoes

etc.

Is it possible to somehow change the link address for users without changing of catalogues structure on server?

so even if all will be done in company.php file - user will see the links as:

http://marketplace.com/companies/blueberries

http://marketplace.com/companies/potatoes

Comment: For that you need use .htaccess already in so there is lot about htaccess search it

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. In any case it depends on how you implemented your PHP. In the best case you have used (or should use) a MVC pattern, that separates the concern of how the URL looks and the logic behind it.